# Control may reach end of non-void function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I dunno why xcode is showing this message, have a look at my code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{

    if (annotation==self.mapView.userLocation) {
        return nil;

        NSString *pinID = @"Salvar";
        MKPinAnnotationView *view = (MKPinAnnotationView*)
        [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:pinID];

        if (view==nil) {
            view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:pinID];

            view.canShowCallout = YES;
            view.animatesDrop = YES;

        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have another issue in your code. On your third line you have `return nil`. That means that none of the code within that if statement will ever be run because it always exits the entire method at `return nil`.

Comment: Should i take it off?

Comment: Ultimately I can't answer that because only you can say what you want the logic to be. If you want to always return nil when annotation == self.mapView.userLocation then you can delete all the code within that if block after return nil. If instead you want to run all the code below it, you should remove the `return nil`.

Comment: Also, be warned that `annotation==self.mapView.userLocation` is only testing that the two references point to the same place in memory (that both variables are referencing the exact same instance). If the variables are referencing two different instances that are otherwise equal, the test will still return false. I think what you probably want is `if([annotation isEqual:self.mapView.userLocation]) {`

Answer (score 1):

No return value is provided in the case where `annotation!=self.mapView.userLocation`.

To repair, add an else block to the first conditional, or return something unconditionally before the final close curly.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{

    if (annotation==self.mapView.userLocation) {
        // the code that you have already here
    } else {
        return nil; // or whatever you would return if annotation!= userLocation
    }
    // or, instead of the else above...
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Yes, if that's what it should return in that case.  The right way to zero when discussing a pointer is 'nil'.